# setRetain is not working in Tablayout inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-tablayout

I am facing simple issue.I have two tabs inside one fragment and both the tab have Recyclerview , on click of item the fragment is changed. but when i onBackPressed method is called at a time i lost the previous both tabs data. here is my code of mainfragment

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Completed"));
       tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Not Over"));
       adapter = new PagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
       tabLayout.setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.graytextcolor),
               ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.toolBarPink));

       tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);


       viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
//        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
       tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

           @Override
           public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
               viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
           }

           @Override
           public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

           }


           @Override
           public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

           }
       });
       viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is my PagerAdapter

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Fragment tab1 = new TabCompleteOrders();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Fragment tab2 = new TabNotOver();
                return tab2;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

and here my first Tab fragment class

```
public class TabCompleteOrders extends Fragment {

    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public ArrayList<ProductOrdersDetails> arrayList;
    public ProgressBar pb;
    public Utils utils;
    public ProductOrderAdapter adapter;
    public String pId;
    public RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private Context context;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_complete_orders, container, false);
        pb = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_tab_complete_orders_recylerview);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        context = getActivity();

        //  getBundles();
        init();
        return view;
    }


    private void init() {
        utils = new Utils(getActivity());
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        adapter = new ProductOrderAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList, getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), Constant.COMPLETED);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(),
                recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, final int position) {

                WriteSharePrefrence(getActivity(), ORDERID, arrayList.get(position).getOrderId());
                WriteSharePrefrence(getActivity(), ORDERSTATUS, COMPLETED);
                Fragment fragment = new OrderDetail();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.addToBackStack("orderDeliveryDetails");
                ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_frame_layout, fragment).commit();

            }
        }));
    }
```

So please help me how can i get previous data onBackPress ?

Comment: in your fragment onviewCreated method check for adapter data. if it is not null then notifydatasetchaged

Comment: okay i will check it

Comment: but when i come back from another fragment , i can see another textView which is static. so i think there any issue related to set both the tab. is it possible ?

Comment: you check for adapter for both tabs?

Comment: yes both the tab have one recyclerView and textView but when i come back from next fragment nothing is appear in screen only showing both tabs title.

Comment: have you put condition in both fragments onviewcreated()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138589/discussion-between-sneha-archirayan-and-divyesh).